# R split on delimiter (split) keep the delimiter (split)

Tags: regex, string, r, split

In R you can use the `strsplit` function to split a vector on a delimiter(`split`) as follows:

```
x <- "What is this?  It's an onion.  What! That's| Well Crazy."
unlist(strsplit(x, "[\\?\\.\\!\\|]", perl=TRUE))

## [1] "What is this"    "  It's an onion" "  What"          " That's"        
## [5] " Well Crazy"
```

I'd like to keep the delimiter(`split`) using R.  So the desired output would be:

```
## [1] "What is this?"    "  It's an onion." "  What!"          " That's|"        
## [5] " Well Crazy."
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use `"(?<=DELIMITERS)"`:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=[?.!|])", perl=TRUE))

## [1] "What is this?"    "  It's an onion." "  What!"          " That's|"        
## [5] " Well Crazy.
```

Comment: You don't need all of the backslashes. `unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=[?.!|])", perl=TRUE))` returns the same result

Comment: Would love an option where the split is a sequence (e.g. "[0-9]+") rather than a single character...