# Combining fragmented sentences in an R dataframe

Tags: regex, r, data-cleaning, srt

I have a dataframe which contains parts of whole sentences spread across, in some cases, multiple rows of a dataframe.

For example, `head(mydataframe)` returns

```
#  1 Do you have any idea what
#  2  they were arguing about?
#  3          Do--Do you speak
#  4                  English?
#  5                     yeah.
#  6            No, I'm sorry.
```

Assuming a sentence can be terminated by either

"." or "?" or "!" or "..."

are there any R library functions capable of outputting the following:

```
#  1 Do you have any idea what they were arguing about?
#  2          Do--Do you speak English?
#  3                     yeah.
#  4            No, I'm sorry.
```

Comment: What function did you use to read in the data? What does the data source look like?

Comment: I wrote a function to parse an .srt file into a dataframe. Everything from the srt was removed except for what you see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for all the sentences ending with: `.` `...` `?` or `!`

```
x <- paste0(foo$txt, collapse = " ")
trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=[?.!|])(?=\\s)", perl=TRUE)))
```

Credits to @AvinashRaj for the pointers on the lookbehind

Which gives:

```
#[1] "Do you have any idea what they were arguing about?"
#[2] "Do--Do you speak English?"                         
#[3] "yeah..."                                           
#[4] "No, I'm sorry."
```

---

**Data**

I modified the toy dataset to include a case where a string ends with `...` (as per requested by OP)

```
foo <- data.frame(num = 1:6,
                  txt = c("Do you have any idea what", "they were arguing about?",
                          "Do--Do you speak", "English?", "yeah...", "No, I'm sorry."), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Concise answer but no space between 'what' and 'they' on first line.

Comment: @ScottHorvath It is up to you, but I think Steve's answer is concise and deserves more.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré My apology for the typo.

Comment: @ScottHorvath Fixed the "space" issue and edited to handle the case where a string could end with `...`

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I got. I am sure there are better ways to do this. Here I used base functions. I created a sample data frame called `foo`. First, I created a string with all texts in `txt`. `toString()` adds `,`, so I removed them in the first `gsub()`. Then, I took care of white space (more than 2 spaces) in the second `gsub()`. Then, I split the string by the delimiters you specified. Crediting Tyler Rinker for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493081/r-split-on-delimiter-split-keep-the-delimiter-split), I managed to leave delimiters in `strsplit()`. The final job was to remove white space at sentence initial position. Then, unlist the list.

**EDIT**
Steven Beaupré revised my code. That is the way to go!

```
foo <- data.frame(num = 1:6,
                  txt = c("Do you have any idea what", "they were arguing about?",
                          "Do--Do you speak", "English?", "yeah.", "No, I'm sorry."), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(magrittr)

toString(foo$txt) %>%
gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = "", x = .) %>%
strsplit(x = ., split = "(?<=[?.!])", perl = TRUE) %>%
lapply(., function(x) 
            {gsub(pattern = "^ ", replacement = "", x = x)
      }) %>%
unlist

#[1] "Do you have any idea what they were arguing about?"
#[2] "Do--Do you speak English?"                         
#[3] "yeah."                                             
#[4] "No I'm sorry."
```

Comment: Or maybe: `x <- paste0(foo$txt, collapse = ""); unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=[?.!|])", perl=TRUE))`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Man, I think you want to keep that answer up. Yours is much better. You do not have to deal with all space issues in your solution.  I was about to upvote it.

Comment: Ok will undelete. But it's the same idea, just using `paste0` instead of `toString` to simplify the space issue.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Go for it!

Comment: Why did you have a leading space before "English" in the dataset ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95171/discussion-between-steven-beaupre-and-jazzurro).