# Splitting a string based on a vector of strings in R

Tags: r, split, strsplit

I have the following string and vector:

```
temp = "EarthMars Venus & Saturn PlanetsJupiter"

searchTerms = c("Earth", "Jupiter", "Mars", "Venus & Saturn Planets", "Neptune")
```

I want to split 'temp' based on the strings in 'searchTerms', so that I get the following:

```
result = c("Earth", "Mars", "Venus & Saturn Planets", "Jupiter")
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `stringr` package, you could do:

```
library(stringr)
result = unlist(str_extract_all(temp,searchTerms))

[1] "Earth"          "Jupiter"         "Mars"           "Venus & Saturn Planets"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option similar to this post ([R split on delimiter (split) keep the delimiter (split)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493081/r-split-on-delimiter-split-keep-the-delimiter-split)) is:

```
searchStr <- paste0(searchTerms, collapse = "|")
unlist(strsplit(temp, paste0("(?<=",searchStr,")"), perl = T))

[1] "Earth" "Mars"  " Venus & Saturn Planets" "Jupiter"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner option with only base functions:

`result <- unlist(lapply(searchTerms, function(x) regmatches(temp,regexpr(x,temp))))`