# Split string on delimiter, keeping delimiter before split

Tags: r

The obvious extension of question [R split on delimiter (split) keep the delimiter (split)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493081/r-split-on-delimiter-split-keep-the-delimiter-split) is:
How to split a string keeping the delimiters at the beginning of each part?

```
x <- "What is this?  It's an onion.  What! That's| Well Crazy."
```

solution

```
unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=[?.!|])", perl=TRUE))
```

gives:

```
"What is this?"    "  It's an onion." "  What!" " That's|" " Well Crazy."
```

Whereas I'm looking for:

```
"What is this"    "? It's an onion" ".  What" "! That's" "| Well Crazy."
```

changing the positive lookbehind into positive lookahead doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using a positive lookahead followed by a word boundary marker:

```
x <- "What is this?  It's an onion.  What! That's| Well Crazy."
strsplit(x, "(?=[?.!|].)\\b", perl=TRUE)

[1] "What is this"     "?  It's an onion" ".  What"          "! That's"        
[5] "| Well Crazy."
```

### Demo